# Can the Firebase user id change?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Can the Firebase user id change? What I talk about is this, `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()` If user delete his account like it is described here [Manage-users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users). I was assuming the `getUid()` id was tied to the E-Mail right, or!?

Comment: I believe if the account is deleted then creating a new account will have a different UID. The UID is a randomly generated ID, not something that is for example hashed from the email address (I'd put this as an answer but I'm not 100% certain).

Comment: I am quite certain UIDs are not based on email addresses, so deleting an account for a specific email address, then deleting it, and then recreating it, will result in a new UID. Please post as an answer @MichaelBleigh.

Comment: fwiw, you cannot change the uid -- it cannot be changed -- but you can actually set its value when you're creating an auth user. This is done via firebase admin sdk. If not provided, a random uid will be automatically generated. Ref: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I was assuming the getUid() id was tight to the E-Mail right, or!?

Not "tied" in the sense of "derived from". "Tied" in the sense of "associated with".

Remember that the email can be changed. When that happens, of course the id is left as is.

You can easily test this in the Firebase console by creating a new user, checking the ID, changing the email and checking that the ID does not change, then deleting the user and creating a new user with the same email and checking that a new ID has been assigned.

Comment: Thanks good to know. I also notice deleting a Firebase user having signed in with gmail, and then sign in again using the same gmail resulted in a new uid for the same gmail. I think it´s easiest to not let user remove his account right,

Comment: I have a [followup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44100005/when-to-use-firebaseauth-user-uid-and-when-to-use-an-e-mail-as-identifier)

Answer (score 3):

As said by @user663031, the answer "no" is correct.

To add on to @user663031's answer, I'm working on a project, but I have to switch between the live database and the test database. I created a user (in firebase authentication) in both test & live environment with the same email address & password, however the id's are different.

In order to achieve proper tests in both environments, I had to change id stored in real time database so that it matches the "unchangeable id" in authentication.