# When to use FirebaseAuth user uid and when to use an E-mail as identifier

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

With This [**Question in mined**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44091302/can-the-firebase-user-id-change) here´s a follow up question.

Correct me on my assumptions please my learning curve is aggressive :).

If making lets say a chat app having Firebase as backend storage, then using the `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()` uid inside the chat system as a chat member identifier, a bad idea if, you allow users to delete there account, and allowing account linking. The uid would change and that would break the database right?

My next assumption now is that to have a secure user id inside the chat app one can use the signed in E-mail address right because it´s a [trusted provider](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/firebase-talk/liu/firebase-talk/ms_NVQem_Cw/8g7BFk1IAAAJ)!? 
My conclusion is to never use the `getCurrentUser().getUid()` uid as an identifierar for the user or?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a bad idea to use `getCurrentUser().getUid()` but a better idea is to use as an identifier the `email address`. I'm saying this because in the case in which the user is is deleting the account and than returns, the `uid` will be for sure different. Because Firebase does not allow the dot symbol `.` in the key, the email address must be encoded like this:

> name@email.com -> name@email,com

As you probably see, i have changed the `.` with `,`. To do this, i recomand you using this methods:

```
static String encodeUserEmail(String userEmail) {
    return userEmail.replace(".", ",");
}

static String decodeUserEmail(String userEmail) {
    return userEmail.replace(",", ".");
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Great maybe I´m on the right way lol. Isn't it a bit programmatically cumbersome  with E-mail, what about hashing it and use the hash for keys everywhere

Comment: Not at all, actually it's quite simple. You only need to encode the user email once, when you add it into the database and decode it, only if you want to display it. Regarding hashing is not necessary. Want can you do is to save it in `SharedPreferences` and use it than across the whole application.

Comment: With Facebook one can create an account only using phone number. How to handle that?

Comment: Because Facebook does not provide the phone number of the user and as far as i know there is no api for doing this, you'll need to use the `uid`. Unfortunately there is no other option in this case.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. It feels like the `uid` in this case can be used, I mean how could it change. If not allowing user to delete the Firebase user account and recreating it the `uid` is a unique identifier right or!?

Comment: If you think that my answer helped you in any way, consider accepting it and giving a +1. Thank you!