# Repurpose Firebase's Facebook Login ID as a Data Key?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

How can I utilize a user's Firebase ID ("id" : "1234567890") as a key for a separate data set within the same db?

the following would be my login detail where I would pull the ID from:

```
"users": {
    "1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" : {
        "dp" : "https://www.profilePic.com",
        "first_name" : "John",
        "id" : "1234567890",
        "last_name" : "Doe",
        "token" : "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890",
        "uid" : "987654321"
    }
}
```

Within Firebase Functions I currently have my code as:

```
admin.database().ref('location_config/{id}').set({current_location:[34.047220, -118.443534]})
```

The result currently comes out as:

```
"location_config": {
    "{id}": {
        "current_location": [34.047220, -118.443534]
    }
}
```

But this is how I would like the data to appear with the ID being the key:

```
"location_config": {
    "1234567890": {
        "current_location": [34.047220, -118.443534]
    }
}
```

The screenshot below illustrates how the UID is dynamic while the ID is constant. 
[image: Firebase RTDB screenshot]

Here is the code within Firebase:

```
let fbLocation;

module.exports = (event) => {
  event.geoFire = functions.database.ref('users').onUpdate(event => {

  admin.database().ref('/portal_coordinates_all').once('value', snapshot =>{ 
    fbLocation = snapshot.val(); 
    console.log ("snapshot", fbLocation);
  }).then(() => {

    // Create a Firebase reference where GeoFire will store its information
    let firebaseRef = admin.database().ref('geofire');

    // Create a GeoFire index
    let geoFire = new GeoFire(firebaseRef);

    geoFire.set(fbLocation)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Provided key has been added to GeoFire");
      }).catch(err => console.log(err))
      .then(() => {

        let geoQuery = geoFire.query({
          center: [34.047220, -118.443534],
          radius: 2
        });

        let locations = [];

        let onKeyEnteredRegistration = geoQuery.on("key_entered", function(key, location, distance) {
          locations.push(location);       
        });

        // fires once when this query's initial state has been loaded from the server.
        let onReadyRegistration = geoQuery.on("ready", function() {
          console.log("GeoQuery has loaded and fired all other events for initial data");

          console.log(locations);

          // ******* here is where I'm having the issue *******
          admin.database().ref( 'location_config/`${id}`' ).set( {current_location: locations} )
          // **************************************************                 

          // Cancel the "key_entered" callback
          onKeyEnteredRegistration.cancel();
        });
      }).catch(err => console.log(err))
    })
  })
}
```

And here is the code within React Native:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  ActivityIndicator,
  Button
} from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { loginSuccess } from '../actions/AuthActions';

const FBSDK = require('react-native-fbsdk');

const { LoginManager, AccessToken } = FBSDK;

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     showSpinner: true,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fireBaseListener = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(auth => {
      if (auth) {
        this.firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref('users');
        this.firebaseRef.child(auth.uid).on('value', snap => {
          const user = snap.val();
          if (user != null) {
            this.firebaseRef.child(auth.uid).off('value');
            this.props.loginSuccess(user);
          }
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({ showSpinner: false });
      }
    });
  }

  onPressLogin() {
    this.setState({ showSpinner: true })
        LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions([
          'public_profile',
          'user_birthday',
          'email',
          'user_photos'
        ])
        .then((result) => this.handleCallBack(result),
          function(error) {
            alert('Login fail with error: ' + error);
          }
        );
  }

  handleCallBack(result) {
    let that = this;
    if (result.isCancelled) {
      alert('Login canceled');
    } else {
          AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
          (data) => {
            const token = data.accessToken
            fetch('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me?    fields=id,first_name,last_name&access_token=' + token)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((json) => {
              const imageSize = 120
              const facebookID = json.id
              const fbImage = `https://graph.facebook.com/${facebookID}/picture?height=${imageSize}`
             this.authenticate(data.accessToken)
              .then(function(result) {
                const { uid } = result;
                that.createUser(uid, json, token, fbImage)
              });
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
              console.log(err);
            });
          }
        );
    }
  }

  authenticate = (token) => {
    const provider = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider;
    const credential = provider.credential(token);
    return firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential);
  }

  createUser = (uid, userData, token, dp) => {
    const defaults = {
      uid,
      token,
      dp
    };
    firebase.database().ref('users').child(uid).update({ ...userData, ...defaults });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      this.state.showSpinner ? <View style={styles.container}><ActivityIndicator animating={this.state.showSpinner} /></View> :
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <Button
            onPress={this.onPressLogin.bind(this)}
            title="Login with Facebook"
            color="#841584"
          />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  }
});

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log('mapStateToProps', state);
  return {
    logged: state.auth.loggedIn,
    user: state.auth.user
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { loginSuccess })(Login);
```

Comment: You'll need to use backquotes for the template literal and use a `$` prefix: ``admin.database().ref(`location_config/${id}`)``. This also assumes that `id` has the correct value in your function.

Comment: @frank-van-puffelen since I haven't defined what the value of `id` is (1234567890) it's resulting in an error. I'm trying to grab a snapshot, make that into a variable, `id`, then crossing my fingers it'll work.

Comment: If you want ID to be the UID of the user that is triggering the function, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42750060/getting-the-user-id-from-a-database-trigger-in-cloud-functions-for-firebase. Not that it'll be easier to help if you edit your question to include the [minimal *complete* code that reproduces where you're stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There's a bit too much guesswork involved right now to allow us (or at least me) to be very effective.

Comment: @frank-van-puffelen [I tried the work around as laid out by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42750060/getting-the-user-id-from-a-database-trigger-in-cloud-functions-for-firebase) @jacobawenger but that seems to pull only the value of UID (`var uid = event.auth.variable ? event.auth.variable.uid : null;`). Since I'm going after the value of the ID I figured it would be as easy as `var uid = event.auth.variable ? event.auth.variable.id : null;`. Unfortunately that didn't work. The reason I'm avoiding to use the UID is because it changes every time on login.

Comment: @frank-van-puffelen, something I left out originally that may help is that the login details are from a Facebook authorized login. The ID, `users.{uid}.id`, and token, `users.{uid}.token`, are unique and stay the same because they belong to Facebook.

Comment: A Firebase Authentication user has a unique UID that stays the same every time a user signs in.

Comment: @frank-van-puffelen I added a screenshot of my database which shows the UID being different per login (green square) for the same person. This is why I'm trying to use the ID (red square). Is there another UID that I'm not looking at?

Comment: That depends on where you get this value from. Please share the [minimal code needed to reproduce the inconsistent UIDs](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @frank-van-puffelen i've uploaded code from both React Native and Firebase Functions.

Comment: If you simply run the React Native code two times and sign in with the same Facebook user, you see different values for `auth.uid` in `onAuthStateChanged`? If so, the problem has nothing to do with Cloud Functions and your MCVE can be much much simplified.

Comment: @frank-van-puffelen So if my understanding is correct, every time I log into the app using Facebook login, the UID should stay the same. The fact that I'm assigned a new unique ID every time I log into the app means that I need to revisit my RN code. You've been a great help.

Comment: @frank-van-puffelen talking this over with my group I realize I made a very very amateur mistake. Since our app is a work in progress it didn't have a logout feature. In order for me to invoke a function I deleted my authentication profile every time. This meant that my UID changed every time I logged back in. I truly apologize for wasting your time with this silly mistake. Nevertheless, I greatly appreciate your help. I will file this under things my bootcamp didn't teach me.

Comment: Ah, that would indeed explain both the stable Facebook ID and the changing Firebase UID. Good to hear that you figured out the root cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After banging my head against the wall as to why I couldn't grab the Facebook ID, it turned out that there isn't a need to grab this ID since Firebase's UID stays constant. I was unaware that the [Firebase ID didn't change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44091302/can-the-firebase-user-id-change) because in my test environment I would always login resulting in a new UID being created.